# Tensorflow: customise LSTM cell with subtractive gating

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I want to use subtractive gating which is explained in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02448.pdf) 
I'm using Tensorflow, and currently the code is: (Using CPU)

```
import tensorflow.contrib.rnn as RNNCell 

tgt_cell = RNNCell.LSTMCell(num_units=flags.hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
tgt_dropout_cell = RNNCell.DropoutWrapper(tgt_cell, output_keep_prob=self.keep_prob)
tgt_stacked_cell= RNNCell.MultiRNNCell([tgt_dropout_cell] * self.opt.num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
```

According to the paper the changes are as follows:
where LSTM is:

[image]

The gating should be subtractive rather than multiplicative:

[image]

when I click on "LSTMCell" in my code, it opens rnn_cells.py and I'm not sure which part should be changed. May someone please help to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

wow thats kind of advanced. Look like RNNCell.LSTMCell and write your own with changes you want. If you look here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py i guess the operation for cells are defined in call like  starting from line 220  then find ops you need.